# Issue with API Platform React Generator

Tags: reactjs, api-platform.com

Following the [API Platform Get Started tutorial](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution#a-reactredux-progressive-web-app), I get an error message when I list the books:

"NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Console shows: *mixed active content « http://api/books »*.

It seems that it's because CORS is restrictive. Setting "allow_origin: ['*']" in nelmio_cors.yaml doesn't resolve the problem.

Could you please help?

Remark: "Create", "Edit" and "Show" APIs work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed in API Platform 2.3.6.